# Euler group - what is the generator element of $U_{10}$?

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to generate $U_{10}$ (Euler group; multiplicative group of units modulo $10$) with $3$.

If $U_{10}=\{1,3,7,9\}$, let's try to generate all other elements using $3$:

$$\begin{align*}
\langle 3\rangle = 3 &\longrightarrow 3+3=6\\
&\longrightarrow 6+3=9\\
&\longrightarrow 9+3=12\\
&\longrightarrow 12\bmod 10 = 2\\
&\longrightarrow 2+3 = 5\\
&\longrightarrow 5+3 = 8\\
&\longrightarrow 8+3 =11\\
&\longrightarrow 11\bmod 10 = 1\\
&\longrightarrow 1+3 = 4\\
&\longrightarrow 4+3 = 7\\
&\longrightarrow \text{Done.}
\end{align*}$$

Is this correct ?

Regards,

Comment: My guess is that you're talking about the units of $\mathbf Z/10\mathbf Z$. This is a multiplicative group: if you want to show that $3$ generates it, then you have to look at $3^2 \bmod{10}$, $3^3 \bmod{10}$ and so on.

Comment: This is what I did , didn't I ?

Comment: It wasn't so clear to me. If, once you had calculated $6 + 3 = 9$ you noted, "aha, this is $3 \cdot 3 \bmod 10$, now I need to find $3$ times this" then everything is fine. But why the intermediate step of writing down $6$? And once you have that $3^2 = 9$, why not just multiply by $3$ to get $27 \equiv 7$? I don't see any benefit to taking "multiplication is repeated addition" this seriously!

Comment: Because I won't be able use a calculator in my exam .... thanks :) just wanted to verify .

Comment: @Dylan - I was confused, and still am, about the point of the question. I thought ron was trying to point out that $3$ is a generator of $U(10)$, but the computation supported a generator for $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$. Apparently, $3$ generates both the multiplicative group $U(10)$ and the additive group $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$. Was this what you meant to point out ron?

Comment: @ron: It is incorrect to talk about **the** generator of $U_{10}$: like any cyclic group with more than $2$ elements, $U_{10}$ has *many* generators (it has $\varphi(n)$ generators).

Comment: Good to know ,thanks Arturo!

Comment: what is an Euler group? When I google it I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find a generator of a cyclic group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786452/how-to-find-a-generator-of-a-cyclic-group)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; this is incorrect. You have shown that $3$ generates the **additive** group of integers modulo $10$. Unfortunately, $U_{10}$ refers to the group of *units* modulo 10, the **multiplicative** group modulo $10$.

One reason you should realize that there is something deeply wrong with what you did is that you correctly list the elements of $U_{10}$ as $\{1,3,7,9\}$. However, in the procedure you perform you get *other* elements! You get $2$, you get $4$, you get $5$, you get $6$, you get $8$, you get $0$,... none of which are supposed to be in your group. Surely, if you were doing things right, you would not be able to get elements *not* in the group by performing group operations on elements *of* the group.

You need to consider the *multiplicative* group; so you want to look at $3$, $3^2$, $3^3$, $3^4$, etc. and see if you get all of $1$, $3$, $7$, and $9$ that way.