# The generators of the group $\langle\mathbb{Z}_n,\oplus\rangle$ are all $g \in \mathbb{Z}_n $ for which $\gcd(g,n)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups

I'm trying to find a proof of this:

> The group  $\langle\mathbb{Z}_n,\oplus\rangle$ is cyclic for every $n$, where $1$ is a generator. The generators of the group $\langle\mathbb{Z}_n,\oplus\rangle$ are all $g \in \mathbb{Z}_n $ for which $\gcd(g,n)=1$, as the reader can prove as an exercise.

It is perfectly clear that $1$ generates all $\mathbb{Z}_n$, but I can't get myself to understand the second part or find a way to prove it. Thanks.

Comment: It is proved in the answer of user134824 [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786452/how-to-find-a-generator-of-a-cyclic-group).

Comment: thanks a lot for the referral! now also the role of the bezout identity in the proof is clear!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Use Bézout's identity to prove that if $\,\gcd(g,n)=1$, $1$ can be obtained as a multiple of $g$ (in $\mathbf Z_n$).

Comment: I had a quick look at the bezout identity, but isn't there a simpler way? the text i quoted was from a first year undergrad discrete mathematics script, and the identity was never mentioned before in the text so i doubt this is the way the author imagined the proof, thank you though!

Comment: Isn't Bézout's identity seen in high school? I'll think of a proof without it, but I won't be necessarily as simple…

Comment: i didn't see it, but the referral to another question helped me understand the whole proof including Bézout's identity, so the question is closed - thanks again!

Comment: Anyway, a direct proof would probably consist in proving a particular version of Bézout, i.e. reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I believe Bézout's identity was covered in Chapter 4 of said script already.