# Generator of a quotient group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have one simple question regarding quotient groups.

If there is a quotient group which consists of all remainders when an integer is divided by 12 such group could be considered as a cyclic group generated by a set of integers congruent to 1 or 5 or 11 mod 12.

My problem:
As far as I can understand ( and I would not be surprised if I was totally wrong) cyclic group consisting of all numbers congruent to 1 mod 12 will not include all integers which give remainder 0, hence how such a cyclic group can be considered equal to a quotient group which consists of all remainders when divided by 12.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble parsing the second sentence.  It might just be me but it seems like it is missing a word.  It couldn't hurt to split it up into several smaller sentences if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group is $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$. So its elements are cosets $0+12\mathbb{Z},\ldots, 11+12\mathbb{Z}$. It is generated by, say $a=1+12\mathbb{Z}$. Note however, that *generator* means something different than than what you say. We have $\langle a\rangle\neq \{a\}$ here.

Comment: I am confused because I think that cyclic group Z/12Z is generated by 1+12Z same way Z is generated by 1. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You can also take $a=5+12Z$. Then $2a=10+12Z$, $3a=15+12Z=3+12Z$, etc. So it is not the same way as in $Z$, because $5$ does *not* generate $Z$.

Comment: Hmm, it appears that I simply have no idea what "generated" means in this context... Would it be too much to ask some info on that, sorry if I am wasting your time.

Comment: No problem. But like reading a text in a foreign language, just open the dictionary yourself. A good place to start is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786452/how-to-find-a-generator-of-a-cyclic-group).

Comment: Thanks for your time.