# Why is 9 a generator of a group Z28?

Tags: finite-groups

It says in my book that generators are relatively prime to $28$, so that would be a set of $\{1,3,5,9,11,13,15,17,19,23,25,27\}$, ok i get that. But why is $9$ and in there? I can express $9$ as $3^2$, so why we have to put $9$ in there as all the numbers in $Z_{28}$ could be expressed without it? Same thing goes for $25$ ($5^2$)
Sorry about my english nad ty for the answers

Comment: There is a difference between **additive** and **multiplicative** generators. The book probably meant additive generators.

Answer (score 3):

This set isn't meant to be a generating set (i.e., a set whose members *combine* to generate the whole group), rather *each* member of the set generates the whole group. Repeated additions of $9$ to itself will generate all of $\mathbb Z_{28}$.

Answer (score 1):

The group $\Bbb{Z}_n$ is cyclic, so has a **single** generator. However, there are $\phi(n)$ different choices for this generator, namely all $1\le k\le n$ which are coprime to $n$. So we have 
$$
\Bbb{Z}_{28}=\langle 1\rangle=\langle 3\rangle=\langle 5\rangle=\langle 9\rangle=\cdots 
$$
This has been explained at this site, e.g., here:

[How to find a generator of a cyclic group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786452/how-to-find-a-generator-of-a-cyclic-group)