# Order, primitive roots modulo 19

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

b. Suppose $a$ is some primitive root of $19$ (it must exist for any prime!).

- What is the order of $a^2$, $a^3$, $a^4$, and $a^5($mod $19)$?
- What elements $a^k($mod $19)$, where $k =2, \ldots 18$ will also be primitive roots of $19$? (Formulate as
  an easy-to-use rule and justify.)
- Are these all primitive roots?

c. We are given that $3$ is a primitive root of $19$. Using (b), find all numbers from $2$ to $18$ which
are the primitive roots of $19$. Explain.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You indicated that you knew the group of units $\Bbb Z_p^×$ is cyclic when $p$ is prime. (That's a feather in your cap.)

A root $a$ is primitive $\pmod{19}$ if and only if it has order $18$.

The order of $a^k$ is $\dfrac {18}{(18,k)}$ (a basic fact about cyclic groups.  Here's a [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4484127/1070376)) .  Thus for a primitive root we need $(18,k)=1$.  There's $\varphi (18)=6$ of these.

So, given that $3$ is primitive,
we have  $3,3^5,3^7,3^{11},3^{13},3^{17}$.  $\pmod {19}$, those are $3,15,2,10,14,13$.

For instance $\lvert a^2\rvert =\dfrac {18}{(18,2)}=\dfrac {18}2=9$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs & PSQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).