Order of element $mP$ in a finite abelian group
In a finite abelian group $G$ of order $n$, for an element $P$ and integer $m$, what's the relation between the order of element $mP$ and the order of element $P$?

Here's my proof:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4484127/1070376

In general (abelianess is irrelevant), if $g \in G$, order of $g$, $o(g)=n$, then $o(g^m)=\frac{n}{gcd(n,m)}$, see for example Find the order of the element g^n by already knowing the order of g
